# Create paged tiff file based on file prefixes in a directory using C#

Tags: c#, file, tiff

No need for the tiff file creation as I already have it. I'm just trying to figure out the algorithm to create the files based on pre-fixes of the file names in the directory.

I have a folder called `C:\Policy Images`. in this folder are pictures. the names of the pictures are as follows:

Policy Number / Picture Name as such:

```
AAAAAAA-Pic1
AAAAAAA-Pic2
AAAAAAA-Pic3
ZZZZZZZ-Pic1
ZZZZZZZ-Pic2
FFFFFFF-Pic1
...
```

When creating the tiff files, I need to create 1 tiff per policy number. based on the above, for example, Id have this:

```
 AAAAAAA-1 (containing 3 pages in this tiff file) 
 ZZZZZZZ-1 (containing 2 pages in this tiff file) 
 FFFFFFF-1 (containing 1 page in this tiff file)
```

The problem with my code below is that it is creating a tiff for all files in the directory and not based on policy number. the part of the code that says "`foreach (string s in AllFilesInDirectory)`" needs to be really `foreach` (string s in policy 1/policy 2/policy 3, etc).

how exactly would I do that? im beating my head against a wall right now.

this is what I have so far:

```
string[] AllFilesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(SelectedDirectory);

//get the codec for tiff files
ImageCodecInfo info = null;

foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
         if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
         info = ice;

//use the save encoder
Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;

EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

Bitmap pages = null;

int frame = 0;

foreach (string s in AllFilesInDirectory)
{
   if (frame == 0)
   {
      pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
      //save the first frame
      pages.Save(AppVars.MergedPolicyImagesFolder + "\\" + PolicyNumber + ".tiff", info, ep);
     PolicyNumber++;
   }
   else
   {
      //save the intermediate frames
      ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
      Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
      pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
   }

   if (frame == AllFilesInDirectory.Length - 1)
   {
      //flush and close.
      ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
      pages.SaveAdd(ep);
   }
 frame++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish your goal you need first some means of splitting the filenames. In the following code I depend on the pattern you gave as an example. If the real filenames have a different pattern, you need to adapt the splitting part of the code (maybe with the help of regular expressions). After the splitting you need to group by policy. In C# this is done with the extension method `GroupBy`, thanks to LINQ. Here is a small code snippet that shows the general idea:

```
var data = new [] {
    "AAAAAAA-Pic1",
    "AAAAAAA-Pic2",
    "AAAAAAA-Pic3",
    "ZZZZZZZ-Pic1",
    "ZZZZZZZ-Pic2",
    "FFFFFFF-Pic1"
};

var splittedEntries = data.Select(entry => {
    var parts = entry.Split('-'); // adapt to real pattern of filenames
    return new { Policy = parts[0], Picture = parts[1] };
});

var groups = splittedEntries.GroupBy(entry => entry.Policy);
foreach (var grp in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine("Do somethin for group {0}", grp.Key);
    foreach (var entry in grp) {
        Console.WriteLine("  * {0}", entry.Picture);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! im going to review to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: how do I go about getting the substringing of the array list? instead of the collection being "AAA-Pic1", "AAA-Pic2", etc. it's actually "C:\Policy Images\AAA-Pic1", "C:\Polic Images\AAA-Pic2", etc.

Comment: I need to grab only the AAA-Pic1 to do the splitting

Comment: If all you are concerned about is to strip the path, then use the `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` method. In the above code snippet exchange the commented line with this one: `var parts = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(entry).Split('-');`